Are there web or software applications that can give anagrams, blanagrams, or letter banks, provided a word?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forms_of_word_play says

Anagram: rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new
word or phrase
Ambigram: a word which can be read just as well mirrored or upside
down
Blanagram: rearranging the letters of a word or phrase and
substituting one single letter to produce a new word or phrase
Letter bank: using the letters from a certain word or phrase as many
times as wanted to produce a new word or phrase

Are there web or software applications that can give anagrams, blanagrams, or letter banks, provided a word?

And are anagrams and ambigrams and blanagrams and letter banks really germane to learning English?  To me it seems like an utter waste of time if the goal is to learn new vocabulary.  So whether they're even valid resources is debatable.  Better to ask on some word-gaming site, IMO.

You're also supposed to do research before asking a question (as well as checking if it's on topic). If you Google anagram solver, anagram dictionary, etc, you'll (unsurprisingly) find websites that give you anagrams of words/combinations of letters. I don't think you need a website to tell you what a word becomes if you reverse the letters. (Note that blanagram is a word some puzzler made up and isn't in most dictionaries, and word banks likewise, so you may have more trouble with them.)

@TimR They are valuable for English study in that they can help to see the differences between words with confusingly similar spellings side by side, and reduce misspelling and unintentional malapropism.

In addition to searching for "anagram generator", "scrabble solver" is a common term for these.

Google is a better site to ask this question.

Your better of studying what are sum common spelling misteaks. A spellchecker (especially on Word) will only pickup won of the six embolden words as a spelling error. I see little point in anagrams, ambigrams in language learning. Fill in the blanks are fun, useful and challenging tasks. Also called cloze texts

Note, this came from a list of "forms of word play." Such sites are useful for word-based games like Scrabble. Rather than study the sites themselves, I'd highly encourage playing such games as a way of encountering new vocabulary words. I certainly learn from the New York Times' "Spelling Bee" just about every day, though I'm not sure how useful it is for me to know that a nene is a Hawaiian goose...
